# What is the best approximation for sine?

Tags: approximation, transcendental-equations

Can you tell me which is the best approximation for cosine/sine functions. It should also reduce the computational complexity. I've already tried the [Bhaskara I's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhaskara_I%27s_sine_approximation_formula).

Can you suggest me anything better?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How accurate do you want it to be, how simple (or complex), and what operations do you allow? Also, do you want it in fixed or floating point?

Comment: I can afford one multiplication, and an addition/subtraction. And I want it for  fixed point implementaion

Comment: What range of values?

Comment: Actually i want it for simultaneous sine and cosine functions, with the input real/ imag values in between -1 and +1. I want to use these functions for discrete fourier transform

Comment: Looks like you are doing this on a quite limited processor. What are the inputs to your computation? From all your restrictions, it's starting to look like the only possibility would be table lookup, perhaps combined with linear interpolation.

Comment: Though discovered [independently](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976462), the following is equivalent to Bhaskara's: $$\cos\bigg(\dfrac\pi2x\bigg) \simeq \Big(1-x^2\Big) \bigg(1-\dfrac{x^2}{4.5}\bigg),$$ for $|x|\le1.~$

Answer (score 1):

For $-\pi\le x \le \pi $ I found $$\left(\frac{315}{2}\pi^2 - \frac{15}{2\pi^2} \right)x + \frac{175}{2\pi^6}\left( \frac{\pi^2}{5}-3\right)x^3,$$ is it of any help?

Comment: Ya it is of help , but i need to do a modulo operation, to wrap the x^3 back into 0<x<pi.

Comment: @phanitej But does it really work? I had just found it on the net, but I'm afraid it's incorrect. Though, I can't check now.

Comment: I suppose typo's in this formula. Try using $x=\frac \pi 2$ or $x=\pi$. Could you tell where you did find it ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yeah, I checked that once but couldn't doublecheck as I'm at school, so I thought I had typed something wrong in the calculator. It was the result of an Italian graduand, confirmed by who looked like his professor. I guess you're right about the typo.

Comment: @phanitej I'll leave this answer here in case someone finds the typo. In the meanwhile, I'll post another answer with a correct inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you're interested in the following double inequality, valid for $0\le x\le\pi$: $$x\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\le\sin x\le \frac{4x}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi}\right) $$