# Approximating basic trigonometric functions to a integrable form

Tags: trigonometry, approximation, approximation-theory, approximate-integration

I wondered if there is a way of approximating trigonometric functions in terms of basic functions (possibly trigonometric functions) so that one can derive the indefinite integral of said function. The function I have in mind is the following:

$$f(x)=sin(\frac{sin(2x)}{2}+x)$$

The presented function is the one currently hussling me; however, I also ask for a general method if one exists.

Sidenote:

The mentioned function was intended to be used as an approximation for Jacobian Elliptic Functions with proper constants dependent on k to match the period and "fatness" of the function.

Comment: $\cos\bigg(\dfrac\pi2x\bigg)\simeq\Big(1-x^2\Big)\bigg(1-\dfrac{x^2}{4.5}\bigg)~$ for $~|x|\le1.~$ See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976462) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the taylor-series of the function. In this case, it is 
difficult to do it by hand. PARI/GP gives :

```
? sin(sin(2*x)/2+x)
%1 = 2*x - 2*x^3 + 26/15*x^5 - 376/315*x^7 + 1982/2835*x^9 - 57212/155925*x^11 +
 1075684/6081075*x^13 - 50590052/638512875*x^15 + O(x^17)
```