# Estimating $\int_0^1 a^x\ \frac{x(1-x)}{\sin(\pi x)} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I doubt a closed form exists, so I am trying to approximate the integral:
$$I(a)=\int_0^1 a^x\ \frac{x(1-x)}{\sin(\pi x)}  dx$$
I am therefore looking for a function $F(a)$ that provides
$$F(a)\simeq I(a)$$ But I want this to be true for **every value** of $a>0$, and so something like a truncated Taylor series of $I$ would be useless, since for large $a$ it would require adding more and more terms.

Up to this day I found only two promising approximations of $I(a)$:

$\Large{1)}$

Using the inequality (which is a quite good approximation for small values of $x,y$)
$$\frac{x-y}{\log x-\log y}<\left(\frac{x^{\frac13}+y^{\frac23}}{2} \right)^3 $$
I got

> $$F_1(a)=\frac{1+a}{8\pi}+\frac{a^{\frac13}+a^{\frac23}}{6\sqrt3}$$

with a percentage error of roughly $1\%$ for small $a$, growing larger as $a$ grows.

$\Large{2)}$

Using the famous ancient approximation for $\sin x$:
$$\sin x \simeq \frac{16(\pi-x)x}{5\pi^2-4(\pi-x)x}$$
I got

> $$F_2(a)=\frac{a-1}{2\log^3a}-\frac{a+1}{4\log^2a}+\frac{5(a-1)}{16\log a}$$

and this one is tremendously precise, even for very large values of $a$.

However, I am still on the lookout for other, even better, approximations for $I$. These two are the only ones I was able to get. Regarding the first one, I tried even sharper bounds known for the logarithmic mean, but then I wasn't able to integrate. The generalized mean of exponent $\frac13$ was the best I could get. I like the result because it features only polynomials, no exponentials or logarithms and trig functions. But, since the two means start to differ very fast past around $10$, the result is good only for small values of $a$.

If someone has an idea to get another approximation I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: I bet @ClaudeLeibovici will come and help.

Comment: Rewrite the integral as $a^{1/2}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\, e^{u\log a}\frac{1/4 - u^2}{\cos\pi u}\, du$. Expand the ratio term as a power series about $u = 0$ and integrate.

Comment: @bob. You won !

Comment: @Zima Your second one is a quadratic function approximation $\frac{x(1 - x)}{\sin (\pi x)} \approx \frac14x^2 - \frac14x + \frac{5}{16}$. I think you can find a better quadratic function approximation with smaller relative error for the integral.

Comment: Notice that the major improvement from $n=3$ to $n=5$ results from a reduction of the norm by a factor of only $20$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^1 a^x\ \frac{x(1-x)}{\sin(\pi x)} \,dx=\frac 1 {\pi^3}\int_0^\pi a^{\frac{t}{\pi }}\frac {(\pi -t) t  }{\sin(t)}\,dt$$

Using the [approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715358/where-am-i-violating-the-rules)

$$\sin(t) \sim \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \big(\pi-t)\,t\big)^i$$ Using partial fraction decomposition,
$$I=\frac 1 {\alpha_n\pi^3}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i\int_0^\pi \frac {a^{\frac{t}{\pi }}}{(\pi-t)\,t + r_i}$$ where $r_i$ are the roots of the polynomial in $\left((\pi-t)\,t\right)$.

Not typed here, but
$$J_i=\int \frac {a^{\frac{t}{\pi }}}{(\pi-t)\,t + r_i}$$ is rather simple (just exponential integral functions). So, we have the analytical solution.

Now computing for $\color{red}{n=3}$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & \text{approximation}  & \text{solution} & \log_{10} (\Delta) \\
 2 & 0.3920162 & 0.3920226 & -5.192 \\
 3 & 0.4956114 & 0.4956200 & -5.069 \\
 4 & 0.5902104 & 0.5902210 & -4.974 \\
 5 & 0.6789496 & 0.6789623 & -4.897 \\
 6 & 0.7634522 & 0.7634670 & -4.831 \\
 7 & 0.8446922 & 0.8447090 & -4.774 \\
  8 & 0.9233101 & 0.9233290  & -4.724 \\
  9 & 0.9997554 & 0.9997763 & -4.679 \\
 10 & 1.0743580 & 1.0743810 & -4.639 \\
 11 & 1.1473694 & 1.1473944 & -4.601 \\
 12 & 1.2189865 & 1.2190135 & -4.567 \\
 13 & 1.2893671 & 1.2893962 & -4.536 \\
 14 & 1.3586403 & 1.3586715 & -4.506 \\
 15 & 1.4269132 & 1.4269464 & -4.479 \\
 16 & 1.4942760 & 1.4943112 & -4.453 \\
 17 & 1.5608054 & 1.5608426 & -4.429 \\
 18 & 1.6265674 & 1.6266067 & -4.406 \\
 19 & 1.6916195 & 1.6916608 & -4.384 \\
 20 & 1.7560119 & 1.7560553 & -4.363 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now computing for $\color{red}{n=5}$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & \text{approximation}  & \text{solution} & \log_{10} (\Delta) \\
  2 & 0.39202261460  & 0.39202261484 & -9.619 \\
  3 & 0.49561996139  & 0.49561996171 & -9.495 \\
  4 & 0.59022101656  & 0.59022101696 & -9.399 \\
  5 & 0.67896224538  & 0.67896224585 & -9.321 \\
  6 & 0.76346696591  & 0.76346696647 & -9.254 \\
  7 & 0.84470898943  & 0.84470899006 & -9.197 \\
  8 & 0.92332901858  & 0.92332901930 & -9.146 \\
  9 & 0.99977631759  & 0.99977631838 & -9.101 \\
 10 & 1.07438098536  & 1.07438098623 & -9.060 \\
 11 & 1.14739440629  & 1.14739440724 & -9.022 \\
 12 & 1.21901352319  & 1.21901352422 & -8.988 \\
 13 & 1.28939621688  & 1.28939621798 & -8.956 \\
 14 & 1.35867148680  & 1.35867148799 & -8.926 \\
 15 & 1.42694643731  & 1.42694643857 & -8.898 \\
 16 & 1.49431121861  & 1.49431121995 & -8.872 \\
 17 & 1.56084261213  & 1.56084261355 & -8.848 \\
 18 & 1.62660669023  & 1.62660669173 & -8.824 \\
 19 & 1.69166082762  & 1.69166082920 & -8.802 \\
 20 & 1.75605524845  & 1.75605525010 & -8.781 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: That's very precise! I wonder if you wrote down the resulting formula for $n=3$, since I'm very curious to know how it looks like. As always, thank you for your work.

Comment: @Zima. In the edit of the linked question of mine, you will find the results. I did not think interesting to reproduce them here. I made the same for $n=5$. What is pure beauty is the so simple result given by Tyma Gaidash

Answer (score 4):

The OP asked a quick question about this question where [@user170231 answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4756452/905886) expanding a special case of @Mariusz Iwaniuk’s hypergeometric function. If we expand the general case, then the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) appears:

$$\,_4\text F_3\left(2,b,b,b;b+1,b+1,b+1,b+1;1\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2)_n(b)_n^3}{(b+1)_n^3n!}=b^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+1}{(n+b)^3}=\frac{b^3}2\left(2\psi^{(1)}(b)+(b-1)\psi^{(2)}(b)\right)$$

Therefore:

$$\boxed{\int_0^1 a^xx(1-x)\csc(\pi x)dx=\frac{i(a-1)}{2\pi^2}\psi^{(1)}\left(\frac{i\ln(a)}{2\pi}+\frac12\right)-\frac{(a+1)}{4\pi^3}\psi^{(2)}\left(\frac{i\ln(a)}{2\pi}+\frac12\right)}$$

shown here:

[image]

Comment: This is pure beauty ! I just feel ridiculous with my approximations. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Only **closed-form**  with **Matematica**:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{a^x (x (1-x))}{\sin (\pi  x)} \, dx=\color{blue}{-\frac{4 a \pi  \, _4F_3\left(2,\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i \log (a)}{2 \pi },\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i \log (a)}{2 \pi },\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i \log (a)}{2 \pi
   };\frac{5}{2}+\frac{i \log (a)}{2 \pi },\frac{5}{2}+\frac{i \log (a)}{2 \pi },\frac{5}{2}+\frac{i \log (a)}{2 \pi };1\right)}{(-3 i \pi +\log (a))^3}+\frac{-4 i \pi  \psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{\pi +i \log
   (a)}{2 \pi }\right)+(-2-2 a-i a \pi +a \log (a)) \psi ^{(2)}\left(\frac{\pi +i \log (a)}{2 \pi }\right)}{8 \pi ^3}}$$

MMA code:

`HoldForm[ Integrate[ a^x*(x*(1 - x))/Sin[Pi x], {x, 0, 1}] == -(( 4 a \[Pi] HypergeometricPFQ[{2, 3/2 + (I Log[a])/(2 \[Pi]),  3/2 + (I Log[a])/(2 \[Pi]),  3/2 + (I Log[a])/(2 \[Pi])}, {5/2 + (I Log[a])/(2 \[Pi]),  5/2 + (I Log[a])/(2 \[Pi]), 5/2 + (I Log[a])/(2 \[Pi])},  1])/(-3 I \[Pi] + Log[a])^3) + (-4 I \[Pi] PolyGamma[ 1, (\[Pi] + I Log[a])/( 2 \[Pi])] + (-2 - 2 a - I a \[Pi] + a Log[a]) PolyGamma[ 2, (\[Pi] + I Log[a])/(2 \[Pi])])/(8 \[Pi]^3)]`

Using:
$$\frac{1}{\sin (\pi  x)}=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } 2 i \exp (-(2 k+1) i \pi x)$$
Then we have:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{a^x (x (1-x))}{\sin (\pi  x)} \, dx=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \int_0^1 a^x (x (1-x)) 2 i e^{i (-1-2 k) \pi  x} \, dx=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } -\frac{i e^{-2 i k \pi } \left(-2 a (-2 i+\pi +2 k \pi +i
   \log (a))+2 e^{2 i k \pi } (2 i+\pi +2 k \pi +i \log (a))\right)}{(\pi +2 k \pi +i \log (a))^3}=-\frac{4 a \pi  \, _4F_3\left(2,\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i \log (a)}{2 \pi },\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i \log (a)}{2 \pi
   },\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i \log (a)}{2 \pi };\frac{5}{2}+\frac{i \log (a)}{2 \pi },\frac{5}{2}+\frac{i \log (a)}{2 \pi },\frac{5}{2}+\frac{i \log (a)}{2 \pi };1\right)}{(-3 i \pi +\log (a))^3}+\frac{-4 i \pi 
   \psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{\pi +i \log (a)}{2 \pi }\right)+(-2-2 a-i a \pi +a \log (a)) \psi ^{(2)}\left(\frac{\pi +i \log (a)}{2 \pi }\right)}{8 \pi ^3}$$

Comment: @Zima. My expression is correct.If I put `a=1` give me: $$\frac{i \left(\pi ^2-7 \zeta (3)\right)}{4 \pi ^2}+\frac{(-4-i \pi ) \psi
   ^{(2)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-2 i \pi ^3}{8 \pi ^3}=\frac{7 \zeta (3)}{\pi
   ^3}$$

Comment: My mistake, didn't see the last part