# Do trigonometry mentally

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I know that sound a bit stupid, but is there a way to calculate basic trigonometric functions mentally like:
$$
\sin(x)
$$
$$
\cos(x)
$$
$$
\tan(x)
$$
$$
\arcsin(x)
$$
$$
\arccos(x)
$$
$$
\arctan(x)
$$
I know it's a lot of functions, but if you can give me a simple and nice writen answer, that would be very nice!

Comment: You can for example calculate them with power series expansions or using geometry, looking at the unit circle or triangles.

Comment: There is no real point in being able to calculate these functions mentally, really.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I know, but I want just a simple method to approximate those functions

Comment: You google "sin(23 degrees)" and you get an approximation.

Comment: If you remove the "mentally" part then the question becomes one that has interest.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez if you want to answer this question without the mentally, do it, that would be great

Comment: One might consider a digital calculation to be "mental" if mental just means not done using physical writing with pen or book. Empirically the human mind is just electrical signals and a computer is the same. Alternately one could memorize a table of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Taylor Series expansion. For example, $$\sin x= x - \frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\dots$$
So as $x \approx 0$ $\sin x \approx x-\frac{x^3}{6}$. Since the error grows a bit larger as $x$ grows, you may also want to use the fact that $\sin x$ is a periodic function. Thus $$\sin(x+2 \pi)=\sin x$$
You can calculate $\cos$ and other trigonometric functions in similar ways. For $\cos$, the expansion is $$\cos x = 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\dots$$
And since $\tan x =\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, you can calculate the tangent as well.  Other tools you could use include the double angle formula, and you can approximate using well known values such as $$\sin \frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \quad  \sin \frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{1}{2}, \quad \sin \frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
Or, somewhat less known but still famous $$\sin \frac{\pi}{12}=\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}$$
For the inverse trigonometric functions, the Taylor series for $\arcsin$ is as follows $$\arcsin x=x+\frac{1!!}{2!!}\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{3!!}{4!!}\frac{x^5}{5}+\dots$$Where $n!!$ is the [double factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html).Then, we have that $\arccos x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin x$. Using these, we can approximate the values required.

Comment: Also double angle formulas can let you push closer to 0 giving better approximations.

Comment: @mathreadler Yes, they do.

Comment: Yes, but, can you give me the "similar ways"?

Comment: @ArthurGuiot See [here](http://www.efunda.com/math/taylor_series/trig.cfm) and [here](http://www.efunda.com/math/taylor_series/inverse_trig.cfm)

Comment: @ArthurGuiot Does my edit address your question?

Comment: @S.C.B. Your edit almost complete my question, do the arcsin, arccos, and arctan, and I will click on the check button :) but thanks a lot

Comment: @ArthurGuiot Editted. Your welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the argument to a multiple of $\pi/2\approx1.57$, i.e. express the angle in "quadrants". It is an easy matter to reduce to the first quadrant.

Then

$$\cos x^*\approx 1-x^2$$ is a resonable approximation ($<5\%$ maximum error, green curve).

You can get better with an extra term,

$$\cos x^*\approx(1-x^2)\left(1-\frac{\pi^2-8}8x^2\right)\approx(1-x^2)\left(1-\frac7{30}x^2\right).$$

($<0.3\%$, blue curve.)

[image]

The sine is obtained from $\sin x^*=\cos(1-x^*)$ and the tangent from the ratio. The arc sine/cosine can be drawn form the first approximation, but require a square root extraction, which is uneasy.

Comment: This looks remarkably similar to my own [empirical approximation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976462).

Comment: @Lucian: no surprise, these are mere polynomial approximations with some tradeoff between accuracy and coefficient simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but it can't be done mentally. And I don't know about inverse functions but I can give you my simple method to calculate $\sin$ of any angle upto at least one digit of accuracy. First, convert your angle to radians if it's in degrees.

If you want to calculate $\sin\theta$ where $\theta$ is in degrees, then first calculate $x=\frac{\pi\theta}{180}$

Now, if $\theta$ lies between 0 and 22.5 degrees, then $\sin\theta=x$ approximately. The accuracy decreases as the angle increases.

If $\theta$ lies between 22.5 and 45 degrees, then $\sin\theta=x\sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{2})^2}$ approximately. The closer $\theta$ is to 45 degrees, the lesser the accuracy.

If $\theta$ lies between 45 and 67.5 degrees, then use $\sin\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x-\frac{\pi}{4}+\sqrt{1-(x-\frac{\pi}{4})^2})$. Accuracy decreases as $\theta$ gets closer to 67.5 degrees.

If $\theta$ lies between 67.5 and 90 degrees, use $\sin\theta=\sqrt{1-(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)^2}$. Accuracy increases as $\theta$ gets closer to 90 degrees.