# Simplifying trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I am a software developer who has run into a wall with a math equation.

I have everything boiled down to this one equation, but I cannot seem to solve for `w`.

My known variables are `r`, `x`, and `s`, and I need to solve for `w`.

$$w = \sin(\frac{\pi(r - xw)}{2(r - s)}) * 2r$$

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Only numerical methods would do it.

Comment: You cannot solve algebraically, only numerically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is too long for a comment.*

The exact way for solving the problem has been given by gt6989b in his/her answer.

Under some conditions, you could **approximate** the solution.

Let me change notation and define $$y=\frac{\pi  (r-w x)}{2 (r-s)}\implies w=\frac{r}{x}-\frac{2  (r-s)}{\pi  x}y$$ The equation becomes $$\frac{r}{x}-\frac{2  (r-s)}{\pi  x}y=2r \sin(y)$$ For $0\leq y\leq \pi$,  a very crude approximation of mine is $$\sin(y)\approx \frac{120 }{\pi ^5}(\pi -y) y$$ which would let you with a quadratic equation in $y$.
$$240 r x y^2+ \left(-240 \pi  r x-2 \pi ^4 r+2 \pi ^4 s\right)y+\pi ^5 r=0$$

Much better would be, for the same range, the magnificent $$\sin(y) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -y) \,y}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -y)\, y}\qquad (0\leq y\leq\pi)$$ proposed, more than $1400$ years ago, by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976462/a-1-400-years-old-approximation-to-the-sine-function-by-mahabhaskariya-of-bhaska)). This will give you a cubic equation to solve.$$8  (s-r)y^3+4 \pi   (r (8 x+3)-2 s)y^2+2 \pi ^2  (5 s-r (16 x+7))y+5 \pi ^3 r=0$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. Thanks for thinking that I can contribute ! I shall look at the problem. Cheers.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. What do you think about my quick answer to the problem you asked me to look at ?

Comment: Thank you so much for the in depth answer! This is fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think an analytic solution exists. You may do better by defining a function
$$f(w) = w - 2r \sin\left(\frac{\pi(r-xw)}{2(r-s)}\right)$$
and doing numerical root-finding to numerically find the value of $w$ which drives your function to $0$, using for example [Bisection Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) or [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) (since derivative is easy to find analytically and implement as well).