# Infinite sum of cosecant, $\frac k{\sin(a+ck)}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, trigonometric-series, ramanujan-summation

## My question

Does S converge or diverge?

*If it converged, ideally I intend to find its explicite expression as a function of c.*

> $S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{\sin(a+ck)}$ where $c\in R^+$

*...within the problem's context the constant c is typically $\approx10^4$ and $a$ is a number $>0$, typically $<10$*

The sum S is part of an anisotropic 3D heat transfer modelling in a cristall like structure. The impact of the sum to diverge would massively alter the overall solution of heat transport.

### What I know

For $\forall c^*=n\pi$ *(with $n\in N$)* the sum converges and becomes a Harmonic Number and can for that special case be calculated.

> $S^*=\pm \frac{1}{\sin(a^*)} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\pm 1)^k\cdot k$*,
>      where the $\pm$ alters wether n is pair or impair*
>
> so that
>
> $S^*=\mp \frac{1}{12\sin(a^*)}$ for pair $n$ and $S^*=\mp\frac{1}{4\sin(a^*)}$ for impair $n$

Still, in the context of the problem c is not not necessarily a multiple of $\pi$.

### What I have tried so far (without success)

In the below several ansatzes which I have considered so far without anyone of them allowing to proceed further:

#### Searching through publications and textbooks

The most extensive list of infinite sums I saw was in [Table of Infinite Products](http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html) (*I am adding the link here as the list there is remarkably extensive*). Still alike other sources, not mentioned here, seemingly the only published infinite sums of cosecant contain the square of csc and multiples of $\pi$.

#### Approximating the cosecant

Any approach alike the one described by  [user Claude](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976462/a-1-400-years-old-approximation-to-the-sine-function-by-mahabhaskariya-of-bhaska) seems not feasible for the impossibility to express infinitely continuing oscillations by polynomials.

#### Mathematica

I aborted Mathematica, after having run the sum using Dirichlet or Borel regularization for 24 hours each. I could let it run longer, but as one cannot see what that program is doing and wether it is "going anywhere", chances are rather slim to succeed with that press-a-button-method.

#### Laplace Transform

The Laplace (nor Fourier) Transform of a cosecant doesn't seem to exist.

#### Intuition

Albeit I risk to get downvoted severely there is a cowboy-mathematics or intuitive (at best) approach. The absolute value of the $\csc$-function $\|\csc(ck)\|$ is repeating once every $ck=\pi$. The value of the sum S can then be thought of taking the sum on only their average values

> $S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{k}{\|\csc(ck)\|}$ _where $(-1)^k$ "simulates the alternating once every $\pi$
>
> For the cosecant average it is
>
> $\|\csc(ck)\|=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{\sin(x)}dx$
>
> As the average must be taken over the range in between 2 consecutive singularities let $\epsilon$ be a very small, positive number close to zero so that the average can be written as (avoiding to say limit)
>
> $\|\csc(ck)\|=\frac{1}{\pi-2\epsilon}\int_{\epsilon}^{\pi-\epsilon}\frac{1}{\sin(x)}dx$
>
> which yields after some transformation and using the first summand of Taylor expansion of the trigonometric terms for $x\rightarrow \frac{\epsilon}{2}$
>
> $\|\csc(ck)\|=-\frac{2}{\pi}\ln(\epsilon)$ and plugged into the sum $S=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(\epsilon)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^kk=\frac{\pi}{8}\ln(\epsilon)$

As $\epsilon$ goes towards zero the above indicates that the sum diverges. Still, this is too intuitive for being reliable, but it is the only indication I have found so far.

#### Identities

The last ansatz I can think of is the use of [trignometric identities](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Csc/introductions/Csc/ShowAll.html), but none of them "triggers eagerness" to explore the sum S by applying anyone of these identities.

### Add-on to orignal post, taking into account comments

Thanks to Igor and Dave for your replies. Still, I have a doubt that the denominator's singularities necessarily bring the infinite sum out of bound; allow me to give 3 examples where the doubt stems from:

> There is a similar sum with a finite (and explicit) result
>
> - $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\csc(k\pi\sqrt2)}{k^3}=-\frac{13\pi^3}{360\sqrt2}$
>
> and another example, an integral taken over one of the singularities (here at x=0)
>
> - $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\csc(x)=C$ *where C is the [Catalan](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html) constant*
>
> both examples can be found in [Introduction to Cosecant](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Csc/introductions/Csc/ShowAll.html).
>
> Using Mathematica I find
>
> - $\sum_{k=1}^{m}\csc(k+a)=\frac{1}{2}(-1+(-1)^m)\csc(a\pi)$
>
> which is supported by one of the numerous [Dieckmann](http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html) results

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I know what you mean. For $c = n \pi,$ all terms in the sum are undefined (since $\sin kn \pi = 0.)$ In general, if $c$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi,$ the terms will be arbitrarily large, so the sum cannot possibly converge.

**UPDATE** adding a constant to the argument of $\sin$ does not materially change things - if $c$ is an irrational multiple of $\pi,$ the denominator will come arbitrarily close to zero, so the terms will blow up.

Comment: You're right. I had forgotten to enter the pretty essential constant $a$. Pardon me; it's corrected now.

Comment: Thanks Igor. I do understand your argument intuitively but I have a doubt - infinite sums are sometimes beyond "common sense". I have illustrated my doubts with some examples in "Add-on to orignal post, taking into account comments ".

Answer (score 0):

There is a necessary condition for series convergence, which is that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is to converge then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. You should check $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\sin(cn)}$ first, and see if it goes to $0$. If the limit is not $0$, then this series must diverge.

Also, certain values of $c$ will make the series undefined, as the denominator could be $0$ at certain points in the summation.

Comment: You're right concerning the denominator being zero for some terms since I had forgotten the essential constant $a$. It's corrected.

Comment: For what concerns the convergence criteria, the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$ e.g. is $\zeta(-1)$ and does converge to $-\frac{1}{12}$ despite its limit going beyond all bonds. So I am not sure to be able to use the criteria as such.