# 2 point quadrature calculation

Tags: numerical-methods

I was curious about how to calculate an approximate value of a definite integral with the 2 point quadrature formula. So I did a test. We all know that:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x)dx = 2$$

Now I tested the quadrature approximation with. 
$$\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)f\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{b+a}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)f\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{b+a}{2}\right)$$

When I calculated this for $a=0$ and $b=\pi$

The value that I got was $4.9$

This is a pretty bad approximation in my opinion. I am wondering if I did something wrong. Can someone check my work?

Also, I used to be able to type in equations here with codecogs, but now I can only link to images. How do you write equations here at stack exchange?

Comment: You can find the detailed MathJax tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I got it to be approximately $1.9358195$

Comment: Actually I redid the calculation and got the right answer. I guess I made some mistake.

Answer (score 2):

As dromastyx commented, you probably have a mistake somewhere since, using the formula as you wrote it, you should arrive, after simplifications, to 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x)dx \approx \pi  \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{3}}\right)\approx 1.93582$$

For the fun, not knowing the values of the trigonometric functions, using [this approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976462/a-1-400-years-old-approximation-to-the-sine-function-by-mahabhaskariya-of-bhaska)
$$\cos(x) \simeq\frac{\pi ^2-4x^2}{\pi ^2+x^2}\qquad (-\frac \pi 2 \leq x\leq\frac \pi 2)$$ you should arrive to $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x)dx \approx \frac{8 \pi }{13}\approx 1.93329$$