# Golden angle for a circle: another definition

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, golden-ratio, transcendental-equations

The accepted definition for the golden angle is based on the ratio of circle arcs, i.e. if $\alpha_0$ is the golden angle in radians, then:

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{a+b}$$

Where $a=\alpha_0 R$ and $b=(2 \pi-\alpha_0) R$.

If the angle is defined as such then we can show that $\alpha_0=(3- \sqrt{5}) \pi$.

(All of the above is according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_angle)).

---

However, if we use the direct generalization of the common definition for the golden ratio for a line segment, we should be comparing areas instead of arc length. Thus, if $\alpha$ is the (new kind of) golden angle, we should define it using the segment area $A$ that we "cut off" by drawing the chord:

[image]

$$A=\frac{1}{2} (\alpha-\sin \alpha)$$

$$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{B}{A+B}$$

We obtain a transcendental equation for the angle:

$$\alpha-\sin \alpha=(3- \sqrt{5}) \pi=2(2-\phi) \pi$$

Numerically its value is:

$$\alpha=2.7664077793984\dots=0.8805749453982892\dots \pi$$

I have not been able to find a closed form.

> Can we find a closed form for $\alpha$? Is it an algebraic multiple of $\pi$ or not?

---

Unlike the common definition, this latter definition of the golden angle can be generalized for the sphere in 3D (cutting by a plane and then comparing volumes) or even the $n-$sphere in any number of dimensions.

---

If I'm correct, then for [a sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) we obtain an equation:

$$(2+\cos (\alpha/2))(1-\cos (\alpha/2))^2=2(3-\sqrt{5})$$

> Which makes $\cos \alpha_{3D}$ algebraic and as far as I understand $\alpha_{3D}$ an algebraic multiple of $\pi$.

$$\alpha_{3D}=2.8228221947949\dots=0.898532211542238\dots \pi$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A closed form cannot be expected.

However, you can have a quite good approximation using (have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976462/a-1-400-years-old-approximation-to-the-sine-function-by-mahabhaskariya-of-bhaska)) using the approximation 
$$\sin(\alpha) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -\alpha) \alpha}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -\alpha) \alpha}\qquad (0\leq \alpha\leq\pi)$$ proposed by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician.

So, the solution of the equation $$\alpha-\sin(\alpha)=k$$ can be approximated solving
$$4 \alpha ^3-4  (k+\pi -4)\alpha ^2+  \left(4 \pi  k+5 \pi ^2-16 \pi \right)\alpha-5
   \pi ^2 k=0$$ In your case, solving the cubic would lead to a quite nasty expression and a value $\approx 2.76692$ while the exact solution is $2.76641$ (as you gave it).

Just for the fun of it, the inverse symbolic calculator found $$\frac{ \sqrt[3]{12}}{10^{3/4}-\sqrt{23}}\approx \color{red} {2.7664077}23$$

Comment: Can we definitely say if it's algebraic multiple of $\pi$ or not? (I think not, but how to prove it?)

Comment: @YuriyS. I don't think either but no proof on my side.

Comment: Claude Leibovici, for a sphere though the case is quite different - see my edit