# Find the inverse of this function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let define the function

$$f(x)=(a+b)\frac{16(\pi+x)x}{5\pi^2+4(\pi+x)x}-b\frac{(\pi^2-4x^2)x}{\pi^2+x^2}$$

for $x \in [\frac{-\pi}{2},0]$ such that $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and  $0<a<b$.

What is the inverse of $f$ on $[\frac{-\pi}{2},0]$ ?

I tried to calculate it several times but I did not succeed.

Comment: Where did this problem come from? Was it inspired by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3768808/1508)?

Comment: @TonyK  this is a modified question from this question https://socratic.org/questions/5a08c0da7c0149261b6c1130 by taking the  Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara  approxiamtion

Comment: @MoonEstrella. The extra $x$ at the end of the equation makes a problem. Are you sure about it ?

Answer (score 3):

*This is not an answer.*

This is amazing since, for $-\frac \pi 2 <x<0$,
$$\frac{16(\pi+x)x}{5\pi^2+4(\pi+x)x} \sim \sin(x)$$
$$\frac{(\pi^2-4x^2)}{\pi^2+x^2}\sim \cos(x)$$ These approximations are $1,400$ years old.

If the problem was (I removed the last $x$)
$$f(x)=(a+b)\frac{16(\pi+x)x}{5\pi^2+4(\pi+x)x}-b\frac{(\pi^2-4x^2)}{\pi^2+x^2}$$ then an *approximation* would be
$$f(x)=(a+b) \sin(x)-b \cos(x)$$ which is a basic trigonometric equation.

Comment: Claude you are too old for me (+1) for the wisdom